# Snapshot a desktop

Tags: windows-7, snapshot

I may be trying to do something that is not possible, but I would like to "snapshot" my desktop every 30min or every hour (Windows 7 Pro).  I work with VMware's snapshot ability which has saved me in the past when running updates or making configuration changes.  I was looking for a way to do this for desktops?  Is this possible?

Thanks
msindle

Comment: Does not seem impossible if you are gonna overwrite snapshots...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you wish to take constant backups such that you can revert to any point in time after a potentially bad change.

System Restore, which is included since Windows XP and pretty good from Vista onwards, provides limited rollbacks of system changes, including driver installation, program installation, Windows updates and some configuration changes. MSI installers, driver installation and program installation will usually automatically trigger the creation of a restore point.

---

If you're looking for something a little more complete, [Acronis True Image](http://www.acronis.com.au/homecomputing/trueimage/) includes what they call [Nonstop PC Backup](http://kb.acronis.com/content/23877):

> Acronis Nonstop Backup provides protection of your disks and files. It allows you to recover entire disks, individual files and their different versions.
>
> Once you start Acronis Nonstop Backup, the program will perform an initial full backup of the data selected for protection. Acronis Nonstop Backup will then save changes in the protected files (including open ones) every five minutes, so that you will be able to recover your system to an exact point in time.
>
> Usually the different states of the protected data will be backed up at 5-minute intervals for 24 hours.
>
> If you select to store Acronis Nonstop Backup changes on a network resource (e.g. on a NAS) and network connection is interrupted, the program stores changes in a temporary local buffer of 1GB and uploads changes to network resource when the connection is restored. If buffer is full and network connection is not restored, Acronis Nonstop Backup pauses.
>
> (!) Backups older than 24 hours are automatically consolidated in such a way that Acronis True Image Home will keep daily backups for the last 30 days and weekly backups until all Nonstop Backup storage space is used. The consolidation will be performed every day between midnight and 01:00 AM. The first consolidation will take place after the Nonstop Backup works not less than 24 hours. If you turn off the Nonstop Backup for some time, the consolidation will start after you turn it on again.

---

You can also manually create incremental backup plans with any good backup software, which will have similar behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

[TimeSnapper](http://www.timesnapper.com/) will do what you want.

Comment: The reference to VMware snapshots and updates/configuration changes indicated the goal is to have a kind of running backup, not pictorial screenshots.

Comment: Bob, after a second read, I agree.  My apologies.